# Lawn Mower Engine Knocking

Tags: lawnmower

To get to the gist, a few days ago the lawn mower had ended up on its side for about 10 minutes. I flipped it back over and didn't use it for about two days.

I started it today. At first it had a bunch of white smoke bellowing out, and a tad bit of oil splashes came out of the exhaust pipe. I kept running it until the white smoke stopped. Once the smoke stopped, a few seconds later the engine started knocking.

I immediately stopped the engine, and checked the oil, which was good.

I removed the spark plug cap to pull the cord and see what it sounded like, [this is what it sounds like](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WZe0RoLdVow&feature=youtu.be).

Any ideas of what the cause may be?

Comment: How did it get flipped over? If you hit something with your blades you could have knocked the timing off which could have caused issues.

Comment: @CodyPace long story short, I was cleaning the bottom of it, and what I used to hold it up didn't have enough weight. It fell, hit my head, and I got pissed at it. *slow clap*

Comment: I assume you looked, but is the blade loose?

Comment: @George the blade is good. I actually just got it sharpened and put it back on. I also turned the blade by hand and the engine still made some not so good noises.

Comment: @George Well, I stand corrected. I flipped it up and grabbed the blade and shook it. It had a bit of shake to it. I torqued it down as hard as I could. I pulled on the cord with the spark plug out and there was no knocking. I fired it up and ran it for a minute or two, and no knocking occurred.

Comment: Don’t torque em down “as hard as you can” because you won’t be pleased if you snap the bolt.. just torque it up “enough to stop the knocking of a loose blade” :)

Comment: A note of caution: At least on our mower, there are tits on the drive shaft flange that key into matching holes in the blade.  If those aren't aligned, the blade can be tightened, but it will loosen up.